# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 ( DB not connecting in node js with mysql)

Tags: mysql

I was building a simple rest API with node and mysql. But while creating the connection to the database I am getting this error.

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
> --------------------
> at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/shehriyarnadeem/Documents/others/learning_projects/linkedinclone/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
> at Protocol.handshake (/Users/shehriyarnadeem/Documents/others/learning_projects/linkedinclone/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
> at Connection.connect (/Users/shehriyarnadeem/Documents/others/learning_projects/linkedinclone/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
> at Object. (/Users/shehriyarnadeem/Documents/others/learning_projects/linkedinclone/config/database.js:12:6)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18) {   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',   port: 3306,   fatal: true }

database.js

> var mysql = require("mysql");
>
> let pool = mysql.createConnection({   host: "localhost",   user:
> "root",   port: "3306" /* port on which phpmyadmin run */,   password:
> "",
>
> database: "dbname", });
>
> pool.connect((err) => {   console.log(err); });
>
> module.exports = pool;

Comment: Nothing was listening at 127.0.0.1:3306. Either you forgot to start the server or you have the wrong IP address or port.

Comment: i am using xampp server so i am sure that is running. But what do you mean by wrong IP address. Thanks in advance.